# Saving Markdown in the database in addition to html in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, markdown, epiceditor

Im using a markdown editor in my rails app that allows users to write their posts in markdown(Epiceditor) and the html is saved to the database. However, this content should be editable as well. At the moment it renders an html mess in the post#edit action. I would need to render the original markdown input, How do I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saving the rendered HTML to the database, save the Markdown content instead.  Then you can simply render the Markdown as HTML for display and serve up the Markdown content for editing.

Comment: yes but at the moment the editor automatically syncs the markdown input to a an input form field that is then saved to the database, so I'm not quite sure how to do this

Comment: So, the Markdown is already saved to the database along with the HTML?